# When is an avocado considered bad?

Tags: spoilage, avocados

I'm generally an avocado purist, so I throw out any brown spots, but I notice that many restaurants serve avocado even with the brown stuff...

When is an avocado considered bad, and when should the chef be notified that there's something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

If it's fully green or even yellow the chances are it's still rock hard.

[image]

Personally a little brown on an avocado is a sign of ripeness,
[image]

I'd regard an avocado that's gone black as completely past it.

https://nuxx.net/gallery/v/moblog/IMG_20100831_090647.jpg.html?g2_imageViewsIndex=1[image]

Comment: what does it mean if an avocado is a greenish brown all over inside of it

Comment: What about in between the second two photos? The latter is obviously bad... The second photo has basically no brown patches - looks more golden

Comment: It's more about the texture. On the first you can see it's perfectly smooth. Whereas the second has clear markings from where it has been sliced. This shows it is softer than the first, so edible soft but not past it's best... Think green banana, ripe banana then black banana 

Comment: The latter looks bad - have received that kind on sushi before. Sometimes the whole thing even tastes rotten!